# Email fails to send with SendGrid and POST using JavaScript / TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, post, sendgrid

I am attempting to send emails with SendGrid's Web API V3. I was able to use Postman to send test emails but it seems Postman doesn't have a way to convert code to plain JavaScript / TypeScript.

My TypeScript is:

```
  emailinvite(){
    var payload = {
      "personalizations": [
        {
          "to": [
            {
              "email": "myemail@service.com"
            }
          ],
          "subject": "Hello, World!"
        }
      ],
      "from": {
        "email": "from_address@example.com"
      },
      "content": [
        {
          "type": "text/plain",
          "value": "Hello, World!"
        }
      ]
    };
    var myHeaders = new Headers({
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": "Bearer API_KEY_HERE",
    });
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append( "json", JSON.stringify( payload ) );
    fetch("https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send",
    {
        method: "POST",
        headers: myHeaders,
        body: data
    })
    .then(function(res){ return res.json(); })
    .then(function(data){ console.log( JSON.stringify( data ) ) })
  }
```

What am I missing to get this functioning?

Answer (score 0):

In this part:

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append( "json", JSON.stringify( payload ) );
```

The docs for the FormData API [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) say that you're setting a key-value pair of json->payload, which is probably not what you want to do... you can probably just do:

```
fetch("https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send",
{
    method: "POST",
    headers: myHeaders,
    body: JSON.stringify(payload)
})
```